# why Oauth redirect to chrome for authentication?

Tags: python, google-chrome, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

I am seeing here https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer they mentioned like in Overview section

> The authorization sequence begins when your application redirects a browser to a Google URL;

*Question*: why all the all the authentication request default going to chrome browser even my client accessing it from mozilla it will redirect to chrome for username and password entry . why ? how to solve this ?

Comment: That seems highly unusual, could you post the code to your oauth callback?

Comment: Oh .. i am developing youtube upload functionality and here is the code https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#upload_a_video

Comment: Thanks, I'm fairly familiar with the YouTube API, I was wondering about your code and what you're trying to do. The behavior you're experiencing sounds like it's related to your callback

Comment: You're writing it in Python, but how is it being delivered ... is it a web app? Or are you distributing the Python code?

Comment: @jlmcdonald because it's a python code, and using  `google-api-python-client==1.2`. yes . it's a web app, when success authentication i am saving it into json file for later functionality